# php soapserver with certificate

Tags: php, ssl, soapserver

I need to setup a php soapserver that only accepts traffic from a specific (validated) certificate. I've searched everywhere, but have not found a way to do that.

I currently use

```php
$server = new SoapServer($this->wsdl);
```

It would be amazing if something like this would work:

```php
$server = new SoapServer($this->wsdl, array('local_cert' => $this->cert_file, 'passphrase' => $this->passphrase));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably this is what you're looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380630/apache-httpd-how-to-trust-specific-client-certificates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a PHP SOAP request with a certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147988/creating-a-php-soap-request-with-a-certificate)

Comment: Thank you DaszuOne, I think it can indeed only be done in Apache, not php.

@Skatox, that answer is about soapclient, not soapserver.